# Change resolution of the video sequencer preview window

Tags: rendering

I am using blender as a video editor on a potato. Is there a way to change the resolution of the Video Sequence Preview window without changing the actual size of the window? My computer is super slow and the resolution of the preview window is really bogging my computer down.

If it simply can't be done, is there other ways I could speed up the on-the-fly rendering of the preview window?

Thanks, Max.

[image: Screenshot of the Video Sequencer Preview window]

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/33814/26640

Answer (score 3):

You can change the scale of the video preview display by selecting a different zoom level in the view menu. You can also use the mouse wheel to zoom in/out. This may not speed up the video display though as the same video still needs to be read and decoded.

[image: view zoom]

To speed up video editing blender uses a [proxy system](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.3/editors/video_sequencer/sequencer/sidebar/proxy.html), which you can find in the Proxy tab of the VSE properties region (press <kbd>N</kbd>). Creating a proxy will generate a set of reduced resolution images that will be used for the video preview. When it comes to the final render the full resolution source will be used.

[image: proxy settings]

Comment: link is currently invalid, is this option still available?

Comment: @Omar yes it is still there, I have updated the link and screenshots