# Blender VSE responsiveness

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Since I just found out about eevee, which is great, I was thinking whether the VSE could be improved real-time as well.

I've noticed that other video editors take time to load projects, but their playback is responsive and smooth. In Blender VSE, however, I open up my project and, well, enjoy my 1-2 FPS playback for the VSE movie projects.

I'm guessing it's just the way Blender works, right? Everyone of you get low FPS in the VSE? If I render a video and then put it in Blender, then it's really smooth - 50 fps or so, but when dealing with raw non-encoded footage is when the fps drops.

Any tips, advice, thoughts?

Comment: Hi, VSE is not the strongest part of blender, of course, so it's not "loved" by devs as most other features... it works, but performance is usually low. In this case though, it could depend on your specific "RAW non-encoded" media, can you specify more about it? size/resolution/framerate, or other.. or share a short sample maybe?

Comment: Advice? Use a real video editing app. Thoughts? Blender is a great 3d content creation app, with an appended and very basic video editing section. If you need performance blender does not compare to any of the highly developed free or commercial apps like resolve, premiere, etc.

Comment: read these related links: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15835/vse-suddenly-slow-like-hell and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33800/vse-how-to-speed-up-the-preview-of-image-strips and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38631/blender-sequencer-speed-is-extremely-slow/87587#87587

Comment: Thanks! The "raw" footage is just clips recorded at 1080p 60fps. I guess that it's just because the files are big (4 - 37 MB per 10 seconds). By encoding them I can save about ten times the size of the clips, but Handbrake has never worked for me properly on Windows, only Linux. Handbrake's exports are smaller in size, but they make the responsiveness in Blender twice as slow, so I leave it out. Rendered Blender footage is smooth when put back in, though.

By the way, the projects consist of a couple of hundreds of clips cut to about 10% of their actual length.